# kill -INT vs kill -TERM

Tags: unix, signals, kill

What's the difference between the `SIGINT` signal and the `SIGTERM` signal? I know that `SIGINT` is equivalent to pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on the keyboard, but what is `SIGTERM` for? If I wanted to stop some background process gracefully, which of these should I use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only difference in the response is up to the developer.  If the developer wants the application to respond to `SIGTERM` differently than to `SIGINT`, then different handlers will be registered.  If you want to stop a background process gracefully, you would typically send `SIGTERM`.  If you are developing an application, you should respond to `SIGTERM` by exiting gracefully.  `SIGINT` is often handled the same way, but not always.  For example, it is often convenient to respond to `SIGINT` by reporting status or partial computation.  This makes it easy for the user running the application on a terminal to get partial results, but slightly more difficult to terminate the program since it generally requires the user to open another shell and send a `SIGTERM` via `kill`.  In other words, it depends on the application but the convention is to respond to `SIGTERM` by shutting down gracefully, the default action for both signals is termination, and most applications respond to `SIGINT` by stopping gracefully.

Answer (score 10):

> If I wanted to stop some background process gracefully, which of these should I use?

The unix list of signals date back to the time when computers had serial terminals and modems, which is where the concept of a *controlling terminal* originates.  When a modem drops the carrier, the line is *hung up*.

**SIGHUP(1)** therefore would indicate a loss of connection, forcing programs to exit or restart.  For *daemons* like *syslogd* and *sshd*, processes without a terminal connection that are supposed to keep running, `SIGHUP` is typically the signal used to restart or reset.

**SIGINT(2)** and **SIGQUIT(3)** are literally *"interrupt"* or *"quit"* - "from keyboard" - giving the user immediate control if a program would go haywire.  With a physical character based terminal this would be the
only way to stop a program!

**SIGTERM(15)** is not related to any terminal handling, and can only be sent from another process.  This would be the conventional signal to send to a background process.

Answer (score 1):

`SIGINT` is a program **interrupt** signal,
which will sent when an user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

`SIGTERM` is a **termination** signal, this will sent to an process to request that process termination, but it can be caught or ignored by that specific process.